# How do you read the definitions of range and domain of a relation aloud?

Tags: definition, relations

In the book I'm reading, I'm given two definition that pertain to relations.

> Suppose R is a relation from A to B. Then the *domain* of R is the set

$$ Dom(R) = \{a \in A \vert \exists b \in B((a,b) \in R)\}$$

> The *range* of R is the set

$$Ran(R) = \{b \in B \vert \exists a \in A((a, b) \in R)\} $$

How would you read these aloud? I'm reading the $Dom(R)$ as "For all $a$ in $A$, there exists some $b$ in $B$ such that $(a, b)$ is an element of $R$." Likewise with $Ran(R)$, I'm reading "For all $b$ in $B$, there exists some $a$ in $A$ such that $(a, b)$ is an element of $R$." I think I understand the definitions, but I feel like I'm reading them wrong.

Comment: No, Dom(R) is defined as those $a \in A$ for which there is a $b \in B$ such that $(a, b) \in R$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“The domain of $R$ is the set of all those $a$ in $A$ for which there exists some $b$ in $B$ with $(a,b)$ in $R$” — You insert a quantity before $a$, but there is none.

Comment: "*You insert a quantity before* $a$" --- Did you mean "You insert[ed] a [quantifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) before $a$"?